# mysql: update a column in one go?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

EDIT : Trying to be more specific here...

I have the following table :

```
SQL> describe dtab;
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| chance | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| base   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| data   | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'd like to know if there's some way to calculate the `base` element of row *n* such that it equals the sum of the `base` + `chance` fields in row *n-1* -- all w/one single sql statement. in other words, starting with a table whose first few rows look like this :

```
| id | chance |  base | data    |
|  1 |     10 |     0 | value1  |
|  2 |     10 |     0 | value2  |
|  3 |  10000 |     0 | value3  |
|  4 |      1 |     0 | value4  |
|  5 |      1 |     0 | value5  |
```

...we would end up with data that look like this :

```
| id | chance |  base | data    |
|  1 |     10 |     0 | value1  |
|  2 |     10 |    10 | value2  |
|  3 |  10000 |    20 | value3  |
|  4 |      1 | 10020 | value4  |
|  5 |      1 | 10021 | value5  |
```

I've tried using a similar approach to how I'd set the values sequentially in rows over an entire table by using a counter variable I've `set` first, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

**ASSUMPTIONS :**

- id's are guaranteed to be sequential.
- the id of a given row is equal to the previous row's id + 1, except for the first row, whose id is 1 [see the table definition].
- the initial `base` value for all rows is 0 [see the table definition].
- the `base` fields are calculated anew each time.

Comment: edited to be a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recurrent problem *(which should be solved some other way; it's usually a symptom that your schema and modeling have some issue. In theory, you should never rely on your rows having a "natural order" and influencing one another, for what happens if you delete one of them?)*.

You need first to **join the table with itself**. As a condition you'll have that the ID of the "table to be updated" is equal to the "table to be read" *plus one*.

This will only work if the ID's are sequential, otherwise you need a more complicated join (still possible, just more complex).

As a test let's create one such table

```
CREATE TABLE test12 ( id integer, base integer, chance integer );
```

and put some values in there

```
INSERT INTO test12 VALUES ( 1, 10, 20 ), ( 2, 20, 17 ), ( 3, 5, 33 );
```

So we have:

```
mysql> select * from test12;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | base | chance |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |   10 |     20 |
|    2 |   20 |     17 |
|    3 |    5 |     33 |
+------+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The update you want is a SET on a JOIN. Note how we need two different aliases (a and b) to allow MySQL to recognize what it is we want done:

```
UPDATE test12 AS a JOIN test12 AS b ON (a.id = b.id + 1) 
       SET a.base = b.base + b.chance;
```

The table is now:

```
+------+------+--------+
| id   | base | chance |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |   10 |     20 |
|    2 |   30 |     17 |
|    3 |   37 |     33 |
+------+------+--------+
```

## Dirty hack (revised question)

You can create a temporary table with the correct base values with

```
SELECT id, base, chance FROM ( SELECT id, @prev AS base, chance, @prev := @prev + chance AS upd FROM test12, (SELECT @prev := 0) AS init ORDER BY id ) AS tmp;
```

...and then you can update `test12` by joining it with the temporary values.

Comment: i was quite excited when i saw this, as it seemed like the solution!  however, when i ran it with undetermined values for `base`, it simply set `base`=`chance` [because `base`, since it defaults to 0, is set to `chance` in `base`+`chance`]. so it seems like the order of evaluation isn't actually what it looks like in the sql. i've updated the question to state the problem in what i think are clearer terms. many thanks for your help!

Comment: @davidfurst Had not considered that case, and yes I should have specified id order. Added a hack to tide you over...

Comment: @LSemi ah! this is really quite clever! :) i didn't know you could use temporary variables that way. thanks, i think i can make this work now.